# Save generated bar code image in database and in folder using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, barcode

I have used library to generate barcode. Bar code is generated but problem is that how can i save that generated image?

Here i am giving my code i have used:

In controller:

```
function add($bar_code)
{
   $postData['bar_code'] = $this->set_barcode($postData['bar_code']);
}

function set_barcode($code)
{
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    $bar_code = Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array('imageType' => 'jpg'))->draw();
    return $bar_code;
}
```

How can i save the image of generated bar code?

Help as son as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: can any one help to solve this?

Comment: Can you not just do an `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to an image file?

Comment: Can you show results of `var_dump($bar_code);`?

Comment: when i write var_dump($bar_code)n that time it just giving me bar code image

Comment: can anyone give me example?

Comment: can any one solve this?

Comment: Check @shultzie comment use these functions or file_put_contents()

Comment: @MikeMiller i don't want to write file. i want to save the image.

Comment: Thats the same thing!

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: @MikeMiller but i don't get file name..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73266/discussion-between-rick-and-mike-miller).

Comment: You decide what to call it. Its very simple. Put the file path and name as argument 1 and the data as argument 2. Try something rather than expect someone else to do your work for you

Comment: but when i ue return $bar_code, it is just displaying image. nothing else

Comment: in var_dump($bar_code); it is not displaying anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the **solution**:

```
function set_barcode($code)
{
   $this->load->library('zend');
   $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
   $file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code), array());
   $code = time().$code;
   $store_image = imagepng($file,"../barcode/{$code}.png");
   return $code.'.png';
}
```

***store the image using imgepng function.

it will store the bar code image in barcode folder.***

Answer (score 0):

We can save `barcode` image into a directory or we can save it into database or both.

```
function set_barcode($code){
    //load library
    $this->load->library('zend');
    //load in folder Zend
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

    //generate barcode
    $barcode = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code, 'barHeight'=>30, 'factor'=>2), array('imageType' => 'png'));

    //set dir path for barcode image store
    $path = './you/dir/path/'.$code.'.gif';
    imagegif($barcode->draw(), $path);

    /* if you want to permanently store your barcode image, and 
       save the path into your database, 
       just return this path. */
    // return $path

    //convert image into base64
    $code_img_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));

    //if you want, remove the temporary barcode image
    unlink($path);

    return $code_img_base64;
}
```