# Cannot insert data barcode with $id_barcode on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to create a barcode using zend_barcode library , when I try to run perfectly but when I try to do a project there is a problem , I try to create a barcode based on $id_barcode I input when I insert does not work .

This my Controllers

```
function insert() {

    $barcode = $this->input->post('id_barcode');
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$barcode), array())->draw();
    $imageName = $barcode.'.jpg';
    $imagePath = './result/';
        if (!is_dir($imagePath)) {
                mkdir ($imagePath, 777, TRUE);
            }
    $createbarcode = imagejpeg($imageResource, $imagePath.$imageName);  
    $this->product_m->insert_produk($createbarcode);
    redirect('admin/product');  
}
```

this my Models

```
function insert_produk($createbarcode){
    $data = array(
                'id_barcode'     => $this->input->post('id_barcode'),
                'reseller_produk'=> $this->input->post('reseller_produk'),
                'nama_produk'    => $this->input->post('nama_produk'),
                'jenis_produk'   => $this->input->post('jenis_produk'),
                'harga_produk'   => $this->input->post('harga_produk'),
                'stock_produk'   => $this->input->post('stock_produk'),
                'date'           => $this->input->post('date'),
                'image'          => $createbarcode);    
   $this->db->insert('tb_produk', $data);  
}
```

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084609/save-generated-bar-code-image-in-database-and-in-folder-using-codeigniter

Comment: thanks @PathikVejani  for the advice, but still unsolved problem , I try to make ( text = > $code) of $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode') ;

Comment: solved... i am forget to load $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode'); in my controllers

Comment: please make your comment an answer in order to have a question and an answer, thanks (btw. you may accept your own answer)