# save barcode using zend barcode generater not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

My code is generating barcodes. but it doesn't save. Please help me to save them.

```
private function set_barcode($code)
{
    //load library
    $this->load->library('zend');
    //load in folder Zend
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    //generate barcode
    $bar_code = Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array('imageType' => 'jpg'))->draw();
    $code = time().$code;
    $store_image = imagepng($bar_code,"../barcode/{$code}.png");
    return $code.'.png';
}
```

Comment: You clearly have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128265/2375207 though it dates back to 2015, they may have upgraded the code?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html#write_file

Comment: Please see this answer. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095574/6570691)